# MySQL query SELECT multiple date brackets from table

Tags: mysql

Consider the following 2 MySQL tables:

#### Table - Commission

| id | employee_id | from_date | to_date | orders_from | orders_to | commission |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-05-01 | 2021-05-05 | 1 | 10 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-05-06 | 2021-05-10 | 1 | 10 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2021-05-11 | 2021-05-15 | 1 | 10 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 2021-05-01 | 2021-05-05 | 11 | 20 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | 2021-05-06 | 2021-05-10 | 11 | 20 | 2 |
| 6 | 1 | 2021-05-11 | 2021-05-15 | 11 | 20 | 2 |
| 7 | 1 | 2021-05-01 | 2021-05-05 | 21 | 30 | 3 |
| 8 | 1 | 2021-05-06 | 2021-05-10 | 21 | 30 | 3 |
| 9 | 1 | 2021-05-11 | 2021-05-15 | 21 | 30 | 3 |

#### Table - Orders

| id | employee_id | order_date | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

An employee will get a commission based on the number of his orders during each date bracket in the "commission" table.

So for example for the first 10(1-10) orders from May 1st till May 5th he'll get 1% for each order and then for  the next 10(11-20) he'll get 2% for each of those and so on.

I'm going to have a form where the manager will be able to select 2 dates from a calendar in order to see what the employee should be paid.

I want to create a MySQL query that will give me all the date brackets from the table "commission" that include the 2 dates the manager has selected?

So lets say that we select the following period:
from **2021-05-03** to **2021-05-09**
How will I get all just the rows for those dates? Which in this case would be ids:1,2,4,5,7,8.

P.S. Data and use case presented here are simplified for better readability/understanding

## EDIT

*After Thomas G's comment*

Lets say that employee with id 1 has the following orders

```
| id   | employee_id | order_date | price |
| :--- | :---------- | :--------- | :---- |
| 1    | 1           | 2021-05-03 | 100   |
| 2    | 1           | 2021-05-07 | 100   |
| 3    | 1           | 2021-05-13 | 100   |
```

Now I want to check what to pay that employee for the period **2021-05-03** - **2021-05-09**.
In that period only the orders 1 and 2 are applicable to be paid.
If we check the commission table we can see that for this period we need records 1 and 2.
How can  get rows 1 and 2 from the commission table, using the 2 dates provided, **2021-05-03** and **2021-05-09**?

Comment: WHERE from_date>=date1 AND to_date <=date2 ?

Comment: That will give you ```from_date>='2021-05-03' AND to_date<='2021-05-09'``` which doesn't match any of the date brackets.

Comment: Then I dont understand the results you want

Comment: I have added an example in my question that maybe will make it clearer

Comment: Now I understand better that you only have one date column to select from, then the syntax should be `WHERE order_date BETWEEN your_date_from AND your_date_to`. Nevertheless it is tedious to provide you with a full answer because we dont know how the commissions should be computed regrading your 1%, 2% rules VS the price and commissions columns. You should describe this and add the results you want for several employees. It is typicaly a question that would require some prepared data on db-fiddle-alike websites

Comment: I'm not trying to make a query on the "orders" table. I want to make a query on the "commission" table. I want to get all the rows, from the "commission" table that the date bracket (commission.from_date-commission.to_date) is part of the search period.